# How to retrieve data for a specific child in firebase database - android studio/ java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data for a specific child, how I can write the code? I try a lot, but it did not work:"([ like in my database here how to get the tasks for specific child like lubna and gets all it's child?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Initialize class variables:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference  lubnaRef = mDatabase.child("tasks/Lubna");
```

And then for testing purposes I am assuming you are calling this in your `onCreate` method of your activity, you'd add the following assuming you do not have a data model for it:

```
lubnaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //These are all of your children.
        Map<String, Object> lubna = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();


        for (String childKey: lubna.keySet()) {
            //childKey is your "-LQka.. and so on"
            //Your current object holds all the variables in your picture.
            Map<String, Object> currentLubnaObject = (Map<String, Object>) lubna.get(childKey);

            //You can access each variable like so: String variableName = (String) currentLubnaObject.get("INSERT_VARIABLE_HERE"); //data, description, taskid, time, title
        }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference lubnaRef = rootRef.child("tasks").child("Lubna");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
lubnaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In the same way you get the `title`, you can also get the other values. The output in your logcat will be:

```
Homework
//and so on
```

Comment: Hi LKB! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?